# How to erase any data linking me to the admin wifi account at my school (just on my PC)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, administrator

So, if I hypothetically obtained the admin wifi password at my school, and it may or may be serious if I were to be found, in the future, could I prevent it? Students are given their own logins to the wifi and the school's file sharing service, and these are monitored quite often. I feel that if I log in to the wifi with my own login, it would hypothetically be obvious to the admin that I "abused computer privileges", which would, hypothetically, have dire consequences. Any legal way to... erm... hypothetically prevent this? Changing the computer's name, MAC address, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to come at this from another angle. Instead of using the mindset of a kid trying to hide something they've done wrong, come at it like an IT security professional who has discovered a vulnerability in someone's system.

Draw up a quick document highlighting just how you were able to obtain the password, ie. you saw the wifi device and searched the internet for it's default password, tried it and found that it worked. Another favorite of mine is a sticky note on someone's screen saying username/password, I saw this at a hospital one time.

Then make some suggestions on how to fix the problem, such as change the passwords away from their defaults. For the sticky note on the screen issue, it is normally related to how people interact with computers, such as the rediculous requirement that some people have about changing passwords every 30~90 days, this only leads to people having easy passwords often combined with month and year and having them written down and stuck to the screen where they use them.

In your report avoid using the names of any individuals and instead say something like 'a teacher' instead of 'Mr Smith' when saying that someone did something insecure. Then give this to the IT admin at the school.